# Error in `arrayBuffer` method of `File` in typescript

Tags: typescript

When I run the following code, I get the error I did in the console. How can I resolve this?

```js
const fileToUint8Array = async (file: File) => new Uint8Array(await (file as Blob).arrayBuffer());
const array = fileToUint8Array(file);
console.log(array);
```

[image]

error is folloing.

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: file.arrayBuffer is not a function. (In 'file.arrayBuffer()', 'file.arrayBuffer' is undefined)
```

I successfully call a method on an arrayBuffer and receive the result. However, even though the method is returning results, I get an error

## Environment in which the problem occurred

tauri 1.2
typescript 4.9.5
react 18

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2029
this is issue is related I think.

Comment: What is `file`? Where are you getting it frmo?

Comment: @vera. thank you for your comment. `file` is `File`object

Comment: Are you sure? This is a runtime error, which means that `file` isn't a `File` object at runtime. Where are you getting it from?

Comment: @vr. The code is like this to minimally reproduce the problem, but it is definitely a `File` object.

Comment: Added: The arrayBuffer method is called, the result is received, and then the error occurs.

Comment: How do you know it's a file object?

Comment: @vr. Because the file is taken from the form file uploader.

Comment: As I added, the arrayBuffer method is called. But I am asking why I get the error. I am certain that I am correct that file is a File object. I would like to discuss the question.

Comment: Can you put some console.log(file) in function fileToUint8Array body? It's possible that due to async something funny is happening between argument evaluation and body of function evaluation.